# Arduino resets when I call network.begin()

Tags: arduino-mega, nrf24l01+, networking, rf

I have included the **RF24Network** library in my project. I tried to use the Simple Transmit/Receive example from [here](https://maniacbug.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/rf24network/) but when it calls the **network.begin()** my arduino restarts. I placed some **Serial.println()** in order to understand where is the problem. This problem appears only in my Arduino Mega 1280. I tried the same code on my Arduino Pro mini and it works like a charm. What causes this? How to fix that? It is very important to use the specific library. Thanks in advance.

Comment: tmrh20.github.io/RF24 is the new and updated library that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the RF24Network library is **not compatible** with the version of Arduino IDE I have. I downloaded Arduino IDE v1.0 and now it works like a charm. I will send an email to maniacbug to tell him about the problem.

Comment: tmrh20.github.io/RF24 is the updated fork.